# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../bower_components/

Tags: html4

I am working on bootstrap 4 . but i will try to import `bootstrap.scss` but its  not working.

Error:-

```
body:before {
white-space: pre;
font-family: monospace;
content: "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: 
../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-
official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss.\A Load path: C:/Users/web-
design/Desktop/testing2/sass\A         on line 1 of C:\Users\web-
design\Desktop\testing2\sass\app.scss\A \A 1: @import 
\"../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-
official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss\";"; }
```

Comment: Do a `bower install`?

Comment: yes  bower will installed .